# Two functions having scheduler and running parallelly using ProcessPoolExecuter

Tags: python-3.x, threadpool, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, concurrent.futures

I am trying to execute two functions parallelly using multiprocessing module in another function and each function have schedule module running once the functions are called. When I run the multiprocessing module function I am able to execute only one function, but I want both of the functions to execute parallelly.

I have tried the following:

```
def func1():
     schedule.every().minute.at(":10").until("23:00").do(job1)
     while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)

def func2():
     schedule.every().minute.at(":10").until("23:00").do(job2)
     while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)

def func3():
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executer:
        executer.submit(func1)
        executer.submit(func2)
```

Only func1 is executing all the time. I have also tried with threading module, but results are the same. Please help how to solve this problem.

Comment: If I replace the `schedule` function calls with simple print statements this program runs just fine.  `func1` and `func2` run in parallel.  Your problem must be somewhere in code you haven't shown us.

Comment: actually my functions has dependencies that depends on web data